# A native speaker says "So I puke out the window" in a film. Could you explain the preposition "out" in this case?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

A native speaker said "**So I puke out the window**" in the film "6 Balloons" (see [the script](https://www.scripts.com/script-pdf/1760)).

Why didn't he say "**so I puke through the window**" or "**so I puke out of the window**"?

It is very strange to use "**out**" like this, which is not often seen in textbooks.

Could you explain the preposition "**out**" in this case?

Comment: It doesn't seem strange to me.  Idiomatically (Br.Eng) I would normally look out of a window, throw something out of a window, etc.  I would probably only look *through* a window if I wanted to emphasise some distortion or lack of transparency introduced by the window material. I am unable to explain it any more than "that's how it is", however, which is why I will refrain from answering.

Comment: but he didn't say "puke out of the window", he said "puke out the window"

Comment: Americans drop the 'of' in such cases more than Brits.  Like they say "grab a couple coffees" whereas I would always say "couple of coffees".  I don't think that really makes any difference to my general point

Comment: In Canada / U.S., you can often shorten (but in my experience, not drop) of to a sound that is like uh/a ("a couple <uh> coffees") said very quickly and almost under the breath.  When looking out (of) a window, dropping the of has a slightly different meaning: "look out the window" means through the window from inside, whereas "look out of the window" means (at least in my circles) pop your head through the open window and look around (maybe even perpendicular to the plane of the window).  Look through the window could imply some dirt or distortion, as suggested

Comment: @stevekeiretsu: "A couple [of]" is an entirely different case. It happens that _couple_ always needs "of" in BrE (_lot_ and _pair_) but the "of" is optional in AmE.  That is an idiosyncrasy of the word _couple_, not part of any systematic difference.

Comment: i've never heard "a couple coffees" (even when I lived in the US), but I won't say it doesn't exist or isn't common in some places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (preposition) sense of the word is in my dictionary ([Lexico/NOAD](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/out)):

> through to the outside.
>
> > - he ran out the door
> > - Then she sat back in her leather office chair and gazed out her corner office window.
>
> [...]
> The use of **out** as a preposition (rather than the standard prepositional phrase **out of**), as in *he threw it **out** the window*, is common in informal contexts, and is standard in American, Australian, and New Zealand English. Traditionalists do not accept it as part of standard British English, however

This matches your example pretty well.

Why would your textbooks not have this? Well, potentially because it’s informal. The subscription only OED marks it as “regional and nonstandard” so I would avoid using it in formal contexts.

Historically speaking it’s a pretty old construct, dating back to Middle English in poetic contexts (such as in [this example from c1300](https://books.google.com/books?id=akb_Iga53kUC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=%22%C3%9Eare%20cam%20An%20Naddre%20out%20%C3%BEe%20gras.%22&source=bl&ots=sK1hUoF9kz&sig=ACfU3U019P5t4iqPhcK6AD0TOtdBaRng7g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIjaTijY7pAhVuhOAKHU1zDIwQ6AEwAHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%9Eare%20cam%20An%20Naddre%20out%20%C3%BEe%20gras.%22&f=false)):

> Þare cam An Naddre out þe gras.
>
> ”There came an adder out the grass.”